# url_launcher Unable to call mobile browser

Tags: flutter, url-launcher

This is my code

```
 void _launchUrl() async {
    userInfo = SpUtil.getMap(Constants.APP_USERINFO);
    if(userInfo['permit']['hua_yan'] == '1'){
      final Uri _url = Uri.parse('http://www.baidu.com');
      if (!await canLaunchUrl(_url)) throw 'Could not launch $_url';
    }
  }
```

Will prompt

```
I/UrlLauncher( 6039): component name for http://www.baidu.com is {com.huawei.browser/com.huawei.browser.Main}
```

I used some official prompt codes, but still can't, still can't
[https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases，in](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases%EF%BC%8Cin) AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cn.ahlims.ahlims">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

Hope to get help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency in AndroidManifest.xml just above of application

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

***MobileUrl Screen***

```
class MobileUrl extends StatelessWidget {
  const MobileUrl({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   

    void _launchUrlA() async {
      final Uri _url = Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev');
      if (!await launchUrl(_url)) throw 'Could not launch $_url';
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
                _launchUrlA();
              }, child: Text('Click Button'))

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to open the default browser instead of a WebView.  WebView can be opened successfully

Answer (score 0):

This can realize the function I want。

```
 String baseUrl = Get.find<AppConfigService>().baseUrl;
 final Uri url = Uri.parse(baseUrl);
 if (await canLaunchUrl(url)){
    await launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication ,webOnlyWindowName:'_blank');
}
```

Reference links：

https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/launchUrl.html